# Create new column for Dataset within a foor loop - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains students attendance data over the previous year. It looks like this, with lots of columns showing different dates, and numbers showing whether they attended or not on that dat.

```
date                  students  2019-09-03  2019-09-04 ...  ThisYearPossible  ThisYearAttended
0     5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415         2.0  2.0        ...               240               224
1     5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416         2.0  1.0        ...               244               240
2     5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417         2.0  1.0        ...               240               228
3     5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418         2.0  2.0        ...               244               238
4     5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419         2.0  2.0        ...               244               238
..                         ...         ...  ...        ...        ...               ...
207   5d718580a974320c3ddcbb2f         NaN  2.0        ...               240               234
208   5d718580a974320c3ddcbb30         NaN  2.0        ...               240               240
209   5d718580a974320c3ddcbb31         NaN  NaN        ...               230               230
210   5d718580a974320c3ddcbb32         NaN  NaN        ...               240               236
211   5e13ae04b9b219f0b15bf0c9         NaN  0.0        ...                98                88
```

However, some of the columns are NaN, as those students hadnt started school yet. So I am trying to create another column in the dataset called 'StartDate' which shows the date that the child first attended - so they either received a 0, 1 or 2 for attendance.

This is what I have so far:

```
    for i in ThisYeardf.index:
        ThisStudent = ThisYeardf.iloc[i].dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=False)
        ThisStudent = ThisStudent.to_frame()
        StartDate = ThisStudent.index[1]
        #ThisYeardf['StartDate'].iloc[i] = StartDate
        print(StartDate)
```

This receives the start date correctly and prints it out fine. But I cannot seem to make a column and add the start date into it for each pupil. The line commented out above gives me the following error - KeyError: 'StartDate'

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - as follows:

```
    Weirddf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['students', 'StartDate']) 
    result = []
    names = []

    for i in ThisYeardf.index:
        ThisStudent = ThisYeardf.iloc[i].dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=False)
        ThisStudent = ThisStudent.to_frame()
        StartDate = ThisStudent.index[1]
        Student = ThisStudent.iloc[0]
        result.append(StartDate)
        names.append(Student)
        print(StartDate)

    Weirddf["StartDate"] = result
    Weirddf["students"] = names
```